# How do I use ModSecurity's transformation function to encode the request_body

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

I would like to encode a specific part of the RequestBody using ModSecurity
phase 2. I believe using a transformation function could help but I don't know how to get it to just transform the value nested within a hash in the body.

The value of the "details" key in the messages hash to be encoded.

The request body contains a ruby hash

```
{
  "message": {
    "details": "there is an attack here"
  }
}
```

Is that possible in ModSecurity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as ModSecurity is not able to parse Ruby hash object. It would be possible with JSON or XML data though. Remember that encoded data are usable only within ModSecurity and will not reach your application.

Comment: Hi @azurit thank you for this :D

I was meaning json object in the request body through the modsecurity and then to the rails app not ruby hash sorry e.g. ARGS:message[body] 

Is there any documentation stating that the encoded format doesn't reach the application?

Comment: In case of a JSON data, you can access it using this format: ARGS:message.details .

Your application will get raw data (not encoded) in the same way as if you have not used ModSecurity..

Comment: thanks @azurit . i realised the transformation functions make a copy of the data and transforms it for the purpose of runnning it through the rule. however, it's the original data that's sent through. i\ll resolve this thank you.